# @-symbol in C# code

Tags: c#, .net

I was given a project of a some developer and during looking throuhg the code I found such code:

```
public interface IPackage
{
    void @Do();
}
```

I've just seen usage of @ in context with strings. But what does that mean in such context? Can somebody explain please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I searched Google before but with no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` character allows you to give your variables names that are reserved as keywords. A common and useful use case for this is:

```
public static void AnExtensionMethod(this SomeObject @this)
{
    @this.AMethod();
}
```

In your example the `@` seems obsolete in C# as `Do` is not a keyword ([`do` is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx)). [It is in VB.NET though](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), so if this interface will be consumed by VB.NET clients it is needed. In your case it is fine only if there really wasn't any better name for the method than `Do`. As it is now it seems not very readable. Conceptually "package.do" can mean anything so you can call it `x` as well. But maybe in your domain language this is a more precise term.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) states:

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim identifier. Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx):

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is
>   useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The
>   character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier
>   might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the
>   prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim
>   identifier. Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords
>   is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style.